# How to set fill color for selection in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to select a bunch of objects on fabricjs(2.7.0) canvas and show selection as filled with low opacity.

**Current**:
[image]

**Desired**:
[image]

I tried this:

```
fabric.Group.prototype.selectionBackgroundColor = '#2dcfab';
fabric.Group.prototype.backgroundColor = '#2dcfab';
```

But no luck. here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mudin/Lj2eofk1/1/). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You set the `selectionBackgroundColor` to an rgba string to give the color an opacity value.

Example:

```
fabric.Group.prototype.selectionBackgroundColor = 'rgba(45,207,171,0.25)';
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
fabric.Group.prototype.selectionBackgroundColor = 'rgba(45,207,171,0.25)';

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  left: 50,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'green'
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  width: 60,
  height: 60,
  left: 250,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red'
}));

canvas.on('object:selected', function (e) {
  e.target.transparentCorners = false;
  e.target.borderColor = '#cccccc';
  e.target.cornerColor = '#0CB7F0';
  e.target.minScaleLimit = 2;
  e.target.cornerStrokeColor = '#0CB7F0';
  e.target.cornerStyle = 'circle';
  e.target.minScaleLimit = 0;
  e.target.lockScalingFlip = true;
  e.target.padding = 5;
  e.target.selectionDashArray = [10, 5];
  e.target.borderDashArray = [10, 5];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh I am very sorry, I shared wrong jsfiddle. Note: my canvas `preserveObjectStacking: true`